# Symfony/React Resolver Problemas com Babel

Tags: react, symfony, babel

Sou novo com **Symfony/React** e logo me deparo com o seguinte problem...

Não consigo executar os mesmos comandos aos quais encontro em alguns tutoriais (Destinados ao React) na Web, pelo que entendi o "plugin" referido na mensagem de erro se deve a falta do Plugin de mesmo nome (plugin-proposal-class-properties) que inclusive citam link com o comando especifico para a instalação do mesmo.

> Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to
>   the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

Obviamente eu tentei instalar o mesmo tanto através do comando NPM como do YARN mas o mesmo erro continua como se não houvesse alterações; a solução temporária encontrada foi remover o com a nova nomemclatura (Arrown Function)

Procurando no google cai em outras respostas através do StackOverflow em inglês ao qual sugeriam a inserção do arquivo **.babelrc** ou também através do arquivo **babel.config.js** tentei de ambas as formas e mais uma vez, nada feito.

Cheguei a conclusão de que a versão talvez do WebPack/Encore utilizada pelo Symfony para gerênciar o React não está pronta para receber essas "novidades" que ainda estão em fase de teste; o que me confirma essa suspeita é a mensagem na documentação do próprio React escrito

> "Nota: esta sintaxe é experimental e ainda não padronizada."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para todo o caso o erro que retorna diretamente no terminal é algo parecido com isso:

```
 20 | handleSubmit = event => {
    |              ^
 21 |     event.preventDefault()
 22 |     alert(JSON.stringify(this.state))
 23 | }
```

PS: Também sou novo aqui no **StackOverflow**

Referência:
[@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties is ignored in .babelrc](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8711)

Comment: O projeto que você startou, tem um arquivo de configuração do babel ou coisa parecida? Tem algum exemplo pra saber o setup do seu projeto?

Comment: Tentei startar com o .babelrc e também sem o arquivo de configuração
Com o .babelrc eu usei o default que encontrei no site do Babel